# Write query with same conditions but different columns and using aggregate functions

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I am making a system that assigns analysts to customer requirements. I wrote a procedure that searches for the ideal analyst to be assigned to a requirement.

The main tables are:

- grc_analyst (Table of analysts who solve requirements)
- grc_requirement (Table of requirements) Many to One relationship with  grc_analyst. The requirements have a field "due_date" which represents the deadline by which a requirement must be resolved.

The rules for finding the analyst is as follows:

- The number of requirements associated with each analyst must be counted.
- If that number is the same for everyone, that is, analysts have the same amount of requirements assigned,then select the analyst whose average due date for your requirements is furthest from the current date.
- If the number is different, that is, analysts have different number of requirements assigned, then select  the analyst with the least amount of requirements assigned.

Here is the code:

```
    DECLARE @totalRequirementsAnalysts int
    DECLARE @idAnalyst int = null 
    
    SELECT @totalRequirementsAnalysts =count(distinct(a.requirements)) 
    FROM ( 
        SELECT 
            a.id,count(r.id) requirements
        FROM
            grc_analyst a
            INNER JOIN  grc_analyststate ea     ON a.id_analyststate = ea.id AND ea.code = 'A'
            INNER JOIN  grc_analyst_category ac ON a.id = ac.id_analyst 
            INNER JOIN  grc_category c              ON c.id = ac.id_category AND c.code = 'SOAP'        
            LEFT JOIN   grc_requirement r           ON a.id = r.id_analyst AND r.id_requirementstate in (
                SELECT id from grc_requirementstate er where er.code IN ('AS','ER','DL','DC') 
            )
        group by a.id 
    ) a
    
    
    IF  (@totalRequirementsAnalysts = 1)
    BEGIN 
        PRINT 'Analysts have the same amount of requirements assigned'
    
        SET @idAnalyst = (
            SELECT a.id from (
                SELECT TOP(1)
                    a.id,avg (DATEDIFF(DAY,getdate(),r.due_date))average_due_date
                FROM
                    grc_analyst a
                    INNER JOIN  grc_analyststate ea     ON a.id_analyststate = ea.id AND ea.code = 'A'
                    INNER JOIN  grc_analyst_category ac ON a.id = ac.id_analyst 
                    INNER JOIN  grc_category c              ON c.id = ac.id_category AND c.code = 'SOAP'        
                    LEFT JOIN   grc_requirement r           ON a.id = r.id_analyst AND r.id_requirementstate in (
                        SELECT id from grc_requirementstate er where er.code IN ('AS','ER','DL','DC') 
                    )
                group by a.id 
                order by average_due_date DESC
            ) a
        )
    
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        PRINT 'Analysts have different number of requirements assigned'
        SET @idAnalyst = (
            SELECT a.id from (
                SELECT TOP(1)
                    a.id,count(r.id) requirements
                FROM
                    grc_analyst a
                    INNER JOIN  grc_analyststate ea     ON a.id_analyststate = ea.id AND ea.code = 'A'
                    INNER JOIN  grc_analyst_category ac ON a.id = ac.id_analyst 
                    INNER JOIN  grc_category c              ON c.id = ac.id_category AND c.code = 'SOAP'        
                    LEFT JOIN   grc_requirement r           ON a.id = r.id_analyst AND r.id_requirementstate in (
                        SELECT id from grc_requirementstate er where er.code IN ('AS','ER','DL','DC') 
                    )
                group by a.id 
                order by requirements ASC
            ) a
        )
    END
    
    SELECT ga.id from grc_analyst ga where ga.id = @idAnalyst
```

As you can see I am using three queries but "from" part is the same for all three (same join tables with same conditions).This procedure complies with the rule and it works, but I want to reduce the number of queries since there is code that repeats itself.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Aside: Using the alias `a` for both a table and subquery in your first query doesn't make it any easier to understand or maintain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid repeating the code, create a view of the common part of the query and then use that within your 3 queries e.g.

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.grc_analyst_view
AS
SELECT a.id
    , COUNT(r.id) requirements
    , AVG(DATEDIFF(DAY,GETDATE(),r.due_date)) average_due_date
FROM grc_analyst a
INNER JOIN grc_analyststate ea ON a.id_analyststate = ea.id AND ea.code = 'A'
INNER JOIN grc_analyst_category ac ON a.id = ac.id_analyst 
INNER JOIN grc_category c ON c.id = ac.id_category AND c.code = 'SOAP'        
LEFT JOIN grc_requirement r ON a.id = r.id_analyst AND r.id_requirementstate in (
    SELECT id
    FROM grc_requirementstate er
    WHERE er.code IN ('AS','ER','DL','DC') 
)
GROUP BY a.id;
GO

-- QUERY 1
SELECT @totalRequirementsAnalysts = COUNT(DISTINCT(requirements)) 
FROM dbo.grc_analyst_view;

-- QUERY 2
SELECT TOP(1) id
FROM dbo.grc_analyst_view
ORDER BY average_due_date DESC

-- QUERY 3
SELECT TOP(1) id
FROM dbo.grc_analyst_view
ORDER BY requirements ASC;
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this help?

```
WITH base AS
(
  SELECT 
    a.id,
    count(r.id) requirements,
    avg (DATEDIFF(DAY,getdate(),r.due_date)) average_due_date
  FROM grc_analyst a
  JOIN grc_analyststate ea     ON a.id_analyststate = ea.id AND ea.code = 'A'
  JOIN grc_analyst_category ac ON a.id = ac.id_analyst 
  JOIN grc_category c          ON c.id = ac.id_category AND c.code = 'SOAP'        
  LEFT JOIN grc_requirement r  ON a.id = r.id_analyst
  JOIN grc_requirementstate es ON r.id_requirementstate IS NULL OR 
                                  (r.id_requirementstate IS NOT NULL 
                                    AND r.id_requirementstate = er.id 
                                    AND er.code IN ('AS','ER','DL','DC') 
                                  )
  group by a.id 
)
-- etc
```

If you don't like CTEs then you could use a view for the above.

Also I don't know what the rule is for when the left join of the grc_requirement table is null on the date difference average.  That should be fixed if this result is wrong.

Comment: I'm probably missing something, but how does a CTE allow you to only write the code once instead of 3 times?

Comment: @DaleK -- that is how a CTE works... you query against the CTE and the optimizer / compiler stores it in memory or a temp table depending on the size.  It essentially builds a materialized query for you (if the compiler is good).

Comment: @DaleK -- if you use a view like you describe you don't have as much code but all  compilers will still run 3 queries against the tables.  It is easy to see if you look at the execution plan.  With a CTE you are telling the compiler to materialize it so it only runs the query once.

Comment: But you can't select from a CTE 3 separate times unless you store the results in a temp table?

Comment: Or are you suggesting to get all the values in one hit?

Comment: The CTE can create `base`, as shown, for the common part of the overall query, then have three additional queries that produce the three (possible) results along with a column to rank them, and a final query that selects the highest ranked non-null result. One of the nice things is that each query can be debugged by replacing the final `select` with a statement that selects the results of the query being debugged/tested/inspected to understand the intermediate results.

Comment: @DaleK -- yes you can select from it 3 times in additional CTEs -- that is how they work.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I believe you can accomplish what you want with a single query, making use of the window function `FIRST_VALUE` and a sub-query you can obtain exactly the value you want without repeating the query at all. This should also perform better.

It turns out you can't use `DISTINCT` in `COUNT OVER ()` so we have to use a `CTE` and `CROSS APPLY` instead.

```
with cte as (
  SELECT a.id
      , COUNT(DISTINCT r.id) Requirements
      , AVG(DATEDIFF(DAY,GETDATE(),r.due_date)) average_due_date
  FROM grc_analyst a
  INNER JOIN grc_analyststate ea ON a.id_analyststate = ea.id AND ea.code = 'A'
  INNER JOIN grc_analyst_category ac ON a.id = ac.id_analyst 
  INNER JOIN grc_category c ON c.id = ac.id_category AND c.code = 'SOAP'        
  LEFT JOIN grc_requirement r ON a.id = r.id_analyst AND r.id_requirementstate in (
      SELECT id
      FROM grc_requirementstate er
      WHERE er.code IN ('AS','ER','DL','DC') 
  )
  GROUP BY a.id
)
SELECT TOP 1 @idAnalyst = CASE WHEN N.DistinctRequirements = 1 THEN FIRST_VALUE(X.id) OVER (ORDER BY average_due_date ASC) ELSE FIRST_VALUE(X.id) OVER (ORDER BY Requirements ASC) END
FROM cte X
CROSS APPLY (
  SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT Requirements) DistinctRequirements
  FROM cte
) N;
-- While one should normally use an 'order by' clause with 'top' it is meaningless in this case as all rows return the same.
```

And if its a requirement to print which choice was chosen then assign the `requirements` count to a variable and use that in your `IF` statement.

Comment: you will need to add a range clause to the FIRST_VALUE statements or they will not give the results you expect.

Comment: @Hogan can you expand on that comment please. My understanding is that the range is only required when you partition the results.

Comment: Nope -> "ROWS/RANGE is not specified but ORDER BY is specified, RANGE UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW is used as default for window frame. " from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-over-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15  This is expected and the standard.  DB2 and Oracle work the same way.

Comment: @Hogan OK, good call, are you saying that `range` might return multiple rows and that for `first_value` we should use "**ROWS** UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW". I haven't had call to use window framing much.

Comment: My problem with this solution is "COUNT(DISTINCT r.id) requirements". It can take several values  ...which of these values will be evaluated in the CASE sentence? In the original query, COUNT(r.id) could be for example 2 for Analyst1 and 3 for analyst2. So when y evaluating the sentence @totalRequirementsAnalysts =count(distinct(a.requirements)) I get the 2 value and then I know the analysts have different amount of requirements assigned.

Comment: @MarioTigua see my edit where I have changed it to `CASE WHEN COUNT(DISTINCT requirements) OVER () = 1 THEN`.

Comment: Dale -- no I'm saying if you if you don't use unbounded preceding and unbounded following the FIRST() will only look at the rows so far.

Comment: please try out this code and see the difference : https://gist.github.com/hoganlong/c9ef8693255918c86ddd72a85212f82b

Comment: @Hogan - thanks for sticking with this - I really appreciate it. Now once I convert your code to SQL Server (is yours MySQL?) it gives me the same results either way see this [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=08d1461baf5f96e332c76f570e2d4813)

Comment: It is not mysql -- it should be close to running on db2, oracle and sqlserver.  as far as I know mysql does not support values or windows functions.  But it is true I did not test it -- i just wrote it off the top of my head.

Comment: so it look like sqlserver is buggy -- here you see it acting correctly according to the standard (and their documentation I showed before https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=dc8a14f320ba28d997728af85c220952

Comment: @Hogan I'm with you - what I forgot from the answer was `TOP 1` - in this case only the first row result is required - hence why I was confused - but because I was missing the `TOP 1` everyone was confused. Thanks again